# Wordpress sub-menu bug

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm working on a site that has a couple of menu items with sub-menu, it all works as it should. But I don't want the sub-menus to show up on smaller screens, so my solution to that was to load the menu twice once with a depth of 1 so the sub-menus would'nt be there, and show the relevant menu using CSS media queries.

The problem is that even though there is no sub-menu the would be parents still have the `menu-item-has-children` even though there is no children, I have checked in firebug and the sub-menu is definitely not there.

I don't want to make 2 different menu's in the dashboard

Comment: do you have a link to the site you are working on? Just to clarify, You want to the menu on mobile to be the exact same, except hide the submenus?

Comment: It's being built locally, so no link sorry.
Yes, but the problem is more that the menu-item-has-children class shows even though there is no children

Comment: Your solution is really wrong. Why don't you just use one menu, and hide the unwanted submenus with css using media queries? It's better to do it this way, than to load extra html, just to have them shown on mobile, and hide on desktop.

Comment: I have tried that as well, the problem is that on touch devices it requires 2 clicks to activate a link (the first would open the "hidden" sub-menu)